# Is it possible to write $-\frac12n^4-n^3+n^2+\frac32n$ in the form $\frac14n^2(n+1)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$-\frac12n^4-n^3+n^2+\frac32n$ in the form $\frac14n^2(n+1)^2$

I dont see how this is possible however its a question i was set, surely $\frac32n$ will never be able to be placed in that format as it is all multiplied by $n^2$?

Comment: Please give us the **exact** wording of the question you were set.

Comment: the whole question is asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2330733/given-that-sumn-r-2r3-can-be-written-in-the-form-an4bn3cn2dn however i thought i could simplify it as people don't want to read too much so i posted a new one i will delete whichever doesn't get replied to

Comment: Doesn't match for $\,n=-1\,$, so it can't match in general.

Comment: As I suspected, no one is asking you to express that quartic in that form. You made a mistake in the algebra. The values you got for $a,\dots,e$ are not consistent with the last of the five equations in the five unknowns at that earlier question.

Comment: oh okay, thanks, ill try read through it again and fix it (i already did but must of missed it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest coefficient to check is that of $n^4$. On the right hand side it is $\frac14$. Not the same on the left, right?

Actually, your method is pretty easy too, and correct.

Answer (score 2):

For large $n$:

$-\frac12n^4-n^3+n^2+\frac32n <0$.

For all $n$:

$\frac14n^2(n+1)^2>0$