# Show that $n^2$ is a factor of the sum of odd powers $(>1)$ of first $n$ integers

Tags: summation

We can easily show that $n$ is a factor of the sum of $p$-th powers of the first $n$ integers , by assuming that the sum is a general polynomial of order $p+1$, and setting $n=0$, giving a zero constant term (as the sum is the same whether  counted from $0$ or from $1$).

However, it is interesting to note that for odd $(>1)$ values of $p$, $n^2$ is a factor as well, and in fact, $n^2(n+1)^2$ are factors.

> Is there a simple way of showing  that $n^2$ is a factor of the sum of odd powers $(>1)$ of the first $n$ integers, without evaluating the entire summation or equating coefficients for the entire polynomial (and, preferably, without using Faulhabner's formulas and Bernoulli numbers)?

For instance, in the case of the fifth power, 
$$\sum_{r=1}^n r^5=an^6+bn^5+cn^4+dn^3+en^2+fn+g$$
As described above, $g=0$. How can we show that $f=0$ without first evaluating the other non-zero coefficients?

Comment: I disagree with the phrasing of your claim, because $1 + 2 + \dots + n = n(n+1)/2$ is a sum of odd powers of the first $n$ integers, and it is not divisible by $n^2$. Odd powers $\ge 3$?

Comment: Yes, odd powers $\ge 3$. Thanks.

Comment: This follows from [that observation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549823), particularly from the properties of Bernoulli polynomials mentioned in [that answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/554867/75794).

Comment: @ccorn - Thanks for the useful references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start from 
$$2\sum_{r=1}^nr^k=n^k+\sum_{r=1}^n(r^k+(n-r)^k).$$
Now if $k>1$ is odd, we can write 
$$\sum_{r=1}^n(r^k+(n-r)^k)=n^2f(n)+\sum_{r=1}^n(nkr^{k-1}),$$
where $f$ is some polynomial. Now, using the fact that the sum of the $(k-1)$th powers is a polynomial with zero constant term, we have $2\sum_{r=1}^nr^k=n^2g(n)$ for some polynomial $g$.

Comment: And about the same logic can be applied with $(n+1-r)$, thus giving the factor $(n+1)^2$. Nice!

Comment: What a brilliant proof! (+1, accepted) Thanks!

Comment: @ccorn - That was going to be the next question posted :)

Comment: Given the solution and comments above, it can be proven that $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$ are factors of the sum of odd $(>1)$ powers $p$ of the first $n$ integers. Hence, for  $p=3$, having easily determined the constant multiplier as $\frac 14$ (by putting $n=1$), we arrive directly at the well-known closed form of $$\dfrac 14n^2(n+1)^2$$.